# Discard vertex in Unity's vertex shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader

In my situation, I have a mesh grid in Unity, and I want to discard some vertices in vertex shader. 'Discard vertex' means that neither the vertex nor the lines connected with it won't be drawn.

I implemented it by accident, but I think it is not an elegant or safe way. My way is to set the `y` part of the position to an invalid number, i.e. `1.0 / 0`.

Here's part of my code:

```
    // count may be 0, but no crash, and the point will not be drawn, seems all good.
    sum /= count;
    pos.y = sum;
    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(pos);
    return o;
```

Here's my result:

[image: my result]

It shows that some vertices and lines connected with them in green box are not drawn.

I am wondering if there is any other elegant and safe way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify the vertex stream in a stage called "geometry shader", in vertex shader you can only modify values feed to the interpolators that feed the fragment shader

Comment: I never use "geometry shader" before and I'll learn it later. I wonder if it is possible that the default geometry shader does exact what I want after I set the vertex position with an invalid value.

Comment: the problem with dividing by zero is that what happens is unspecified. While the shader is guaranteed not to crash, it may do something else on a different graphics card

Comment: I learned how to write a simple geometry shader yesterday. I discarded the triangle in geometry shader and get the same result as dividing by zero before. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

From opengl spec:

> Similarly, treatment of conditions such as divide by 0 may lead to an
>   unspecified result, but in no case should such a condition lead to the
>   interruption or termination of processing.

You can't discard a vertex in vertex shader, the vertices are still here.

Comment: The vertex may be not actually discarded, but it looks like being discarded. If the vertex is somewhere with a position, that position value is exactly what I want.